# Desktop shows for split second on wake before password requested

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake

If I wake my Mac from sleep I always get a split second flash of my active desktop before the screen is replaced by my usual password unlock screen. When I unlock, I get my desktop as normal, as it appeared in the split second flash (i.e. It's a live flash, not a cached or buffered screenshot from when it was locked).

I'm not particularly fussed, it's merely annoying, but I imagine that simply filming the screen waking would allow a screenshot to be pulled from behind a locked display, which others may find a risk.

Comment: does it do that without screen lock ?

Comment: @Buscar Not sure I understand, without a lock it would just open straight to the desktop anyway?

Comment: you are right (that was a stupid question), my question would be do you see something in the console?

Comment: 09/05/2014 21:26:57.816 WindowServer[107]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [818322756714729]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake

Comment: 09/05/2014 21:26:57.816 WindowServer[107]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Reordering authw 0x7fef5ad3db50(2000) (lock state: 3)

Comment: 09/05/2014 21:27:03.595 loginwindow[76]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.